# Android Acitvity Intent on itself

Tags: android

How can i make an intent on the same Activity?

I have a Activity Lektion which has forward and backwards buttons, and when i hit on the forward button i want to start the same Activity just with other parameters. 
For that i also send a bundle with the Intent.

But the Activity isnt going to be created again as it seems...

```
public class Lektion extends Activity {
    private int rowCount = 0;
    private ArrayList<LektionPage> lektionPages = new ArrayList<LektionPage>();
    private int lektionPage = 0;
    private Bundle bundle;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lektion);

        bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String lektionNummer = bundle.getString("LektionNummer");
        setTitle("Lektion "+lektionNummer);     

        try{
            lektionPage = bundle.getInt("LektionPage");
        } catch(Exception e){}

        forwardImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
                if(lektionPage == rowCount){
                    return false;
                }
                Log.i("ontouch", ""+lektionPage);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Lektion.this, Lektion.class);
                bundle.putInt("LektionPage", lektionPage++);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating the intent without ever firing it.

You need to

```
startActivity(intent);
```

for the Intent to actually be executed.

But id say you should only change the content of the activities view etc instead of creating the activity over and over again

Comment: But how can i change just the content in the activity?

Comment: Depends on the actual content your page shows. There has to be at least one `View` element. You can change its code/content in the `onTouch`

Answer (score 1):

This is an awkward (and maybe impossible) way to handle you requirements.

Consider splitting functionality and navigation using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this can be achieved by using the popper activity launch modes and some logic in the onNewIntent method of the activity.

[Activity Launch Modes 1](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/activity-launch-mode-in-android.html)

[Activity Launch Modes 2](http://intridea.com/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode?blog=company)

I would suggest using the single task launch mode for your activity.

I hope it helps..

Comment: When i do this like that...
Do i have the same code in the onCreate Method as in the newIntent Method!?

Seems a little bit awkward for me.. but i dont know how to do it better here...

Comment: SingleTop would also fit to my needs, or not?

Comment: You can write the code in onNewIntent and then use the getIntent method in onCreate to call onNewIntent.